FNB58 USB Tester: Using as universal power supply
I'm currently carrying quite a lot of different power supplies with me. To avoid additional weight and toolbox size, I would like to reduce it to 1 universal power supply solution.
In total, I need one supply with the following parameters:

5 V < 3 A
9 V < 3 A
15 V < 3 A
18 V < 5 A

I found an interesting post:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ FNIRST model FNB58
Questions:

Is it possible to supply a FNB58 via USB C, manually select the needed voltage and output it on the USB C again to feed it to different devices?
Are all selectable voltage levels predefined or is it possible to set those freely in e.g. 0.1 V steps?


@MrGerber In the latest PD standard they are not predefined but support PPS mode.
